# How to fix "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10000, 60000]"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mnist

I have problem with training my code using Stochastic Gradient Descent and MNIST database.

```
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
    from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

    mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
    X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]

    some_digit = X[36000]
    some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)

    X_train, X_train, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]


    y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)
    y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)

    sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
    sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)
```

Error at the end of process (in my opinion the last verse of code is bad):

```
  ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10000, 60000]
```

Comment: I don't have a setup to test on right now, but perhaps try `sgd_clf.fit(X_train.T, y_train_5.T)`. The problem may be that the shape should be (785, 0) rather than (0, 785)

Comment: Please post the complete error trace (not here, edit & update your post); as is, we can't even know where exactly in your code the error pops up...

Comment: @Alter When I add "T", it says that `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [784, 60000]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo on your side, you are assigning to `X_train` twice:

```
X_train, X_train, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
```

Correct answer would be:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
```

BTW. `fetch_mldata` will be deprecated soon, it would be a better idea to use:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
X, y = fetch_openml("mnist_784", version=1, return_X_y=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a stratified splitting between train and test dataset because some classes might skewed representation in the training.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```